# npm run build command works locally but not in the production server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, build

In my system (react for client-side and node.js for the backend),
when I run `npm run build` locally, the local server runs perfectly without errors.

After a `push` and `pull` I get an error from the production server.

[image]

Here is a part of the `package.json`-

```
"scripts": {    
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"    
  },
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `npm run build` can be anything, it's defined in `package.json` and we don't know what is your configuration. Also, seems like the problem is in a browser's console, not when the project is built

Comment: Thank you ,I added a part of the package.json

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.